# Prevent to invoke webmethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

I have bunch of `webmethod` in my site.Is there any way to check its call from my application or its directly call to invoke , out from my application.

I try this in web.config:

```
<webServices>
      <protocols>
        <remove name="HttpGet"/>
        <remove name="HttpPost"/>
        <remove name="HttpPostLocalhost"/>
      </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Its only prevent to invoke method but open my .asmx file in browser.My plan is to check whether its call from my application or direct browse ? If its direct browse then
I have to prevent  it to open ?
Is there any secure way to do this or I am in wrong way?Thanks.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "authentication". You need to decide who your caller is.

You would then provide "authorization" - making sure that only those callers who are permitted access to the service, actually have access.

Comment: before i post i search in SO and I got this link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555611/is-it-possible-to-secure-a-web-service-with-forms-authentication it says ` Do not use it unless you have no choice at all.`

Comment: It said don't use ***forms*** authentication. Forms authentication isn't the only kind of authentication. ASMX web services, on the other hand, shouldn't be used for new development unless you have o choice at all.